# Effect of parameter ‘Paint’ in Android‘s Canvas.drawBitmap() method

Tags: java, android

I was trying to read sample FingerPaint in Android SDK where the method **`canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint)`** called within **`onDraw()`**.

I was confused by the parameter `mBitmapPaint`. It seemed to have no effect when I changed the settings of `mBitmapPaint`. The style of the bitmap painted on the screen only depends on the settings of `mPaint` defined somewhere else. The Google's Android Reference says that the parameter `paint` may be null, does it mean `paint` here is useless? Why put a paint parameter in this method?

It's declared as:

> **public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,float left,float top,Paint paint)**
>
> Draw the specified bitmap, with its top/left corner at (x,y), using the specified paint, transformed by the current matrix.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **bitmap** The bitmap to be drawn
> - **left** The position of the left side of the bitmap being drawn
> - **top** The position of the top side of the bitmap being drawn
> - **paint** The paint used to draw the bitmap (may be null)

Here is part of the code:

```java
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

mPaint = new Paint();
mPath = new Path();
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

/*
 * Set the styles of mPaint here
 * ......
 */

// Settings of mBitmapPaint seem to make no difference
mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

Comment: for example you can use xfer modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paint for a Bitmap is pretty much useless, I think the only parameter of the paint object that applies for a Bitmap is the AntiAliasing mode wich is turned on by default. I think you can also use the paint for a color filter such as black and white, but for most cases you can just use `null` as well.

Comment: thank you...but is there a rule for that? I can't find in Google's reference

Comment: @Soap what do you mean by 'rule'? And for the reference click [here] ("http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)")

Comment: I mean the rule when to use the paint, but I think I got it, thanks again :)

Comment: The rule is simple: Use one if you need one. If you are okay with the default settings a Bitmap is drawn with, you don't need a paint. But if you want to change something about the settings, e.g. turn off AntiAliasing, you must use a paint.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly used to set antialiasing and bilinear sampling:

- [setAntiAlias(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap(boolean))
- [setFilterBitmap(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setAntiAlias(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, Rect, Paint)` works properly with paint, **BUT** only if Bitmap is in `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8` format. It can be easily converted on the go with `Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true/false)`. It's especially useful with Paint, that has a BitmapShader applied.

It's not mentioned enough, so I thought I'll add an answer to this old question.